# Factoring the sum or difference of two cubes

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring

I'm learning about sums and differences of cubes and I can't understand it very well. I am faced with this problem:

$$x^3 - 27$$

I am told to find the sum or difference of the two cubes. I understand I need to get it into the form of $a^3 - b^3$, which turns out to this:

$$x^3 - 3^3$$

I don't know how to find the sum or difference of cubes. If anyone would care to explain how to do this so I could solve this and other problems like it I would appreciate it. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Are you asking how to factorise the difference of two cubes?

Comment: This is not clear at all. Could you please provide the original question?

Comment: If you're looking to factorize, $a^3 \pm b^3 = (a \pm b)(a^2 \mp ab + b^2)$

Comment: I apologize for not being clear. All the instructions say is "Sum or difference of two cubes" (that is word for word what it says). I assume they want me to factor them but I am not 100% sure.

Comment: you are supposed to find the number whose cube is 27 and then express the whole original expression as x^3-(the number)^3

Comment: So the answer is 3?

Comment: Is the answer "3"? Who knows. You never stated any question.  "$x^3-27$" is not a question. By the way, see [math notation guide](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(STRONG) HINT:If you multiply $(A+B)(A^2-AB+B^2)$ you get $A^3+B^3$ similarly $A^3-B^3=(A-B)(A^2+AB+B^2)$.  So you have $A=x$ and $B=3$. Substitute into the above formula and you will get the factored form.

Answer (score 1):

can you identify a pattern here?
$$x^6+x^5y+x^4y^2+x^3y^3+x^2y^4+xy^5+y^6$$
$$x-y$$

---

$$\begin{array}{rrrrrrrrrrr}
x^7&+&x^6y&+&x^5y^2&+&\dots&+&xy^6&&\\
&-&x^6y&-&x^5y^2&-&\dots&-&xy^6&-&y^7\\
\end{array}$$

---

$$\begin{array}{rrrrrrrrrrr}
x^7&+&0x^6y&+&0x^5y^2&+&\dots&+&0xy^6&-&y^7 = x^7-y^7\\
\end{array}$$

Now try
$$(x+y)(x^6-x^5y+x^4y^2-x^3y^3+x^2y^4-xy^5+y^6)$$

Comment: nice, i like to think of it as adding on terms to $(x^{n-1}+y^{n-1})$ recursively to remove the unwanted terms in the expansion. This keeps going until we get to the middle term. From that we could see that x+y can only be factored out of x^n+y^n when n is odd, but x-y can always be factored from x^n-y^n